# How to have an img in wordpress page template depending on page name (or id, etc)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

so I have a page template with the following code excerpt:

```
<style>#hero::before {background: url(...);}</style>
<section id="hero" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="container position-relative" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
          ...
      </div>
</section>
```

The problem lies in the first paragraph. I need the url for background to change depending on basically any unique identifier of the page, like name or id. My plan is to create a special direction in the media library, something like "uploads/page-bgs/" and name all the images there using page identifiers, for exapmle "background-[pageID].jpg", and also set a default bg in case no such image was found. I'm not very familiar with php and found nothing like that in google, so I need help with the correct php code for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved the problem thanks to the imput from the commenters. Here's the solution:

   <?php $BgImg = '(default image direction)';
    if (file_exists(__ __DIR__ __ .'/../../uploads/backgrounds/'.get_the_ID().'.jpg')) $BgImg = ('(directions)/backgrounds/'.get_the_ID().'.jpg'); ?> 

And then in style: {background-image: url(<?php echo $BgImg; ?>);}

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditions like this:

```
<?php
    $BgImg = 'https://via.placeholder.com/500';
    if ( is_page( 'about' ) ) ) {
         // either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
         $BgImg = 'https://via.placeholder.com/100';
    } else {
         // none of the page about us, contact or management is in view
         $BgImg = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200';
    }
?>

<style>#hero::before {background-image: url(<?php echo $BgImg; ?>);}</style>
<section id="hero" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="container position-relative" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
          ...
      </div>
</section>
```

Here for more details:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: Thank you. This is basically my option if I can't get the current one right, cause there are going to be many pages of that template, but I'll use a giant case statement if nothing else helps.

Comment: You can also use ```get_the_ID();```  to acheive this . ```#hero::before {background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_ID().'.jpg'?>);}```